# Spark-Scala: Incremental Data load in Spark Scala along with generation of Unique Id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `zipWithIndex` to generate `sequence_number` and add it as a separate column.
I am using code similar to below:

```
val file = sparkSession.createDataFrame(lexusmasterrdd,structSchema)
val filerdd=file.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(indexedRow => Row.fromSeq((((indexedRow._2.toLong+1)).toLong) +: indexedRow._1.toSeq))
val newSchema=StructType(Array(StructField("Sequence_number",LongType,true)).++(file.schema.fields))
val finalDF=sparkSession.createDataFrame(filerdd,newSchema)
```

I am now trying to come up with a logic for incremental load for the same.
A simple load where new data is appended to existing data and sequence numbers are generated from last generated number.

One way to achieve this by getting the `max(Sequence_number)` and then adding along with a `row_number()` function for new data.

But is there any other way in which i can make use of `zipWithIndex` in incremental load? 
Some code would be helpful.

I am using Spark 2.3 with Scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One way to achieve this by getting the max(Sequence_number) and then
>   adding along with a row_number() function for new data.

This would work, but does not scale because `row_number()` would need to shuffle all records into 1 partition. I would rather use `monotonically_increasing_id()`:

```
//get max from "old" data
val prevMaxId = oldDf.select(max($"Sequence_number")).as[Long].head()
val addUniqueID : Column = monotonically_increasing_id() + prevMaxId

val finalDF = newDF.withColumn("Sequence_number",addUniqueID)
```

if you want to use `zipWithIndex`, you could something similar:

```
//get max from "old" data
val prevMaxId = oldDf.select(max($"Sequence_number")).as[Long].head()    
val finalRDD = oldRdd.zipWithIndex().map{case (data,id) => (data, id+prevMaxId)}
```

Comment: I didnt try monotonically_increasing_id because it wont be giving a sequential increment of id. let me try the second option you have given